# argparse: make one argument default when no arguments are called

Tags: python, default, argparse

What's the best way to set a group argument as the default when no arguments are called.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--a", action="store_true") #call when no arguments are provided
group.add_argument("--b", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("--c", action="store_true")
```

Let's call my program argparse_ex.py. I want `argparse.py` (with no arguments) and `argparse.py --a` to return the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a simple test after parsing

```
if not any([args.a, args.b, args.c]):
   args.a=True
```

This is simpler than any attempt to make `parse_args` to do this.  The parser will parse all arguments independently - and in any order.  So you really can't tell until the parsing is all done whether any of the options has been selected or not.